# wrong value shows on sell with coinbase pro api

Tags: coinbase-api

I am using coinbase pro api using sandbox and testing a sell case.

The order i am placing is

```
const sellParams:any = {
    'side': 'sell',
    'product_id': 'BTC-USD',
    'type': 'market',
    'size': '0.009'
}
```

the response in order status comes as below

```
{
  "type": "market",
  "id": "5846345c-c070-44bf-9d31-ec07a1c9892c",
  "product_id": "BTC-USD",
  "side": "sell",
  "post_only": false,
  "created_at": "2019-08-12T04:08:29.845922Z",
  "fill_fees": "0.0297509100000000",
  "filled_size": "0.00300000",
  "executed_value": "9.9169700000000000",
  "status": "done",
  "settled": true,
  "done_at": "2019-08-12T04:08:29.853Z",
  "done_reason": "canceled",
  "size": "0.00900000"
}
```

the question is on executed value which shows 9.9169...  should not it be around 100 USD ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so basically sandbox prices are different than the actual prices and thats where the confusion was.

Comment: Are you saying that on their sandbox environment their "executed_value" is just random and has no relation to the other numbers that come back in the response?

Comment: been a while so dont remember now.